# How do I keep a part of my activity fixed and static

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making an app that allows a user to stream a video and then also comment / Ask questions below it, what happens is that when the keyboard is opened the video player is scrolled to make room on the screen for the keyboard.

Layout of the Activity :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2"
tools:context=".LiveVideoBroadcasterActivity">

//player portion starts here

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_weight="0.7">

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview_surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settings_button"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="showSetResolutionDialog"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/changeCameraButton"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="changeCamera"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_switch_camera_white_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/settings_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stream_live_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|top"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_live"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/live_indicator"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 //player portion ends here

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/show_chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/stream_name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/stream_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSelect" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toggle_broadcasting"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:onClick="toggleBroadcasting"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chatbox"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textmassge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:hint="Enter Message"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:ignore="Autofill,HardcodedText" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried  to keep the whole layout in a constraint layout and a give static height and width but, since I need the app to be responsive enough so as to work across multiple devices , I opted for this approach using linearlayout and weightsum.

Comment: have you tried add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` to activity declaration in Manifest?

Comment: @AgiMaulana Yes I did, and it did not work